# Ember.js: Calculate the sum of a property of all child models

Tags: model, ember.js

My application has the following models:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.List = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('App.User'),
    tweetsUnread: function(){
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        // Code to dynamically calculate the sum 
        // of tweetsUnread property of all
        // App.User that are related to this list
        /////////////////////////////////////////
    }
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    screenName: DS.attr('string'),
    tweets: DS.hasMany('App.Tweet'),
    tweetsUnread: function(){
        // TODO: check if this is the correct way to do it
        return this.get('tweets').get('length');
    }.property('tweets.@each'),
    list: DS.belongsTo('App.List')
});

App.Tweet = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
});
```

How can I calculate the sum of all App.User.tweetsUnread and make it automatically update App.List.tweetsUnread?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following should do it. There might be an more concise solution using reduce, but i have never used it myself :-)

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('App.User'),
    tweetsUnread: function(){
        var users = this.get("users");
        var ret = 0;
        users.forEach(function(user){
            ret += users.get("tweetsUnread");
        });
        return ret;
    }.property("users.@each.tweetsUnread")
});
```

**Update:** This is a more elegant solution using reduce. I have never used it and this isn't tested but i am quite confident that this should work:

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('App.User'),
    tweetsUnread: function(){
        var users = this.get("users");
        return users.reduce(0, function(previousValue, user){
            return previousValue + users.get("tweetsUnread");
        });
    }.property("users.@each.tweetsUnread")
});
```

**In Ember 1.1 the API for reduce has changed!** Thx @joelcox for the hint, that the parameters initialValue and callback have changed their position. So here the correct version of the code:

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('App.User'),
    tweetsUnread: function(){
        var users = this.get("users");
        return users.reduce(function(previousValue, user){
            return previousValue + user.get("tweetsUnread");
        }, 0);
    }.property("users.@each.tweetsUnread")
});
```

Comment: Thanks, reduce did the trick (_edited a bit to add the correct params_)

Comment: In recent versions of Ember (at least as of ~1.1), the initial value is the second argument for the reduce method. The callback is the first. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_reduce

Comment: Why is reduce better than +=? Not challenging just curious.

Comment: Using reduce is following a more functional style, where you try to avoid side effects (e.g. assignments). With += you have to check what the loop is actually doing. Reduce already implies a certain operation and you just have to reason about the closure.
But i do not want to start a discussion on functional vs imperative programming here :)

Answer (score 40):

Another option would be to use `Ember.computed.sum` see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_sum)

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('App.User'),

  tweetsUnread: Ember.computed.mapBy('users', 'tweetsUnread'),
  totalTweetsUnread: Ember.computed.sum('tweetsUnread')   
});
```

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft because SO believes that the answer flagged as best answer by the OP should be at the top! :(

Answer (score 4):

When using coffeescript, I like to use the one-line syntax, first getting the property values array with `.mapBy('propertyName')` and then using a simple coffeescript `reduce`:

```
@get('users').mapBy('tweetsUnread').reduce (a, b) -> a + b
```