# Computed property that keeps a running total of values in ArrayController's model

Tags: ember.js

I have an array controller holding a list of models which includes a numeric amount (i.e a dollar value).

Initially the model contains 1 row with an amount of 0, as the user adds rows to the model and changes the amounts I want to keep a running total at the bottom of the list.

I'm about 4 hours into working with Ember and I don't quite understand how to iterate over the model in a computed property and return the sum and most importantly, have it recalculate as I add values to the model.

What I'm trying to use is:

```
totalLoanAmount: function() {
 var t = 0;
  var amounts = this.get('content.@each.amount').toArray(); 
  for (index = 0; index < amounts.length; index++) {
      t += amounts[index];
  }

return t;
}.property('content.@each.amount'),
```

But this doesn't seem to update as I add items to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependent-key part looks correct to me. <strike>But I don't believe you can use `@each` to map properties in the way you're attempting on the third line of your code.</strike> *Edit: OK, it turns out you can do this though I can't find any documentation indicating that this is recommended or expected.*

The quick fix, I believe, would be to use `var amounts = this.get('content').mapBy('amount')`.

But you might also look into refactoring this function using Ember's `reduce` functionality as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933633/ember-js-calculate-the-sum-of-a-property-of-all-child-models).